# Index of generic NPCs in New World of Darkness?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e

**Is there an index of the generic NPCs published in the various nWoD books?**

Notes:

1. The more comprehensive the index, the better.
2. I'd prefer an online index, but if there's one to be found in the books published by WW, that'll do as well.

Answer (score 1):

No.

But there is this [wiki](http://wodindex.wikispaces.com/) page, which contains a few of them from various books, sorted by genre.